can we write a soql query to fetch the accounts where there should be only one or no contacts which are associated to it?
this question is asked in an interview, i tried but I was unable to create an SOQL query, is it possible to write a query like this?

No, not with a single query on its own at least.

You can write such a query, but it requires additional database setup. First, you'll need something like DLRS to count the number of contacts on the account. Once you do this, the query is simply:
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Contact_Count__c <= 1

The syntax you'd need to find those contacts would look something like this:
select
  account.id
from
  account left join contact
on account.id = contact.accountid
  having count(contact.id) <= 1

Unfortunately, Salesforce doesn't recognize this syntax, so that's why you need a rollup summary field.

A single query can fetch you the accounts without contacts but that's all. The query looks like this:
SELECT Id
FROM Account
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact)

That is: "select accounts where the identifier is not found in the relationship field of the contact table".
The problem is the other requirement, that asks for accounts with a single contact. While it is possible to query accounts that way, it would require two queries and a bit of Apex to achieve it, but the only reason is that the query that returns the account identifiers returns an aggregate query, which is not available as a sub-query for this requirement.
You can count accounts with single contacts with this query, using the HAVING keyword:
SELECT AccountId
FROM Contact
GROUP BY AccountId
HAVING COUNT(Id) = 1

But its result isn't usable directly as a sub-query. You can NOT do this, for example:
SELECT Id
FROM Account
WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT AccountId
    FROM Contact
    GROUP BY AccountId
    HAVING COUNT(Id) = 1
)

But if you could, the answer to your question would be a query that uses these two queries I mentioned before as sub-queries.
So, the answer to your question is no. You can't use a single query to fetch data in the conditions you provided. What you can do is what @sfdcfox suggested in his answer: to prepare your data first with a custom field as a rollup, and then query on that field.
